# How to find anti-derivative of $J_0(x)J_1(x)$

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I want to solve following integral$$\int  J_0(x)J_1(x) dx$$I tried so many different ways but I couldn't find a way to attack this problem! please help me

Comment: Think about what is the derivative of $J_0(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the substitution $u=J_0(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the integral representation of Bessel function here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel.27s_integrals

That would be helpful.